# How to edit the shortcut to open a new terminal in KDE Plasma?

Tags: linux, shortcut, kde-plasma

I couldn't find a way to start a terminal (konsole) using a shortcut and all the shortcuts mentioned in other sites don't work.

I tried changing the shortcut to something else but I couldn't find the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit the shortcut to open a new terminal in KDE Plasma:

1. Click the **K** menu from the bottom left corner of your screen and search System settings.
2. Go to **System settings**
3. Locate the **Workspace** section and click on **Shortcuts** within it.
4. Select **Custom Shortcuts** to display the list
5. Click the **+** button at the bottom of the list to create a new shortcut.
6. Enter a name for the new shortcut and specify the command to launch the terminal. If you are using the Konsole terminal emulator, enter the command `konsole`.
7. Click the **None** button and select the desired keyboard shortcut. You can either press the key combination you want or click the **Custom** button to define the shortcut manually.
8. **Apply** and save the changes.

It should open a terminal for your new shortcut by pressing the defined key combination.